# Return an instance attribute when a user submits something

Tags: python, html, django

Right now I'm trying to make an e-commerce site. My problem is that I cant calculate the total amount the user has spent on the current purchase, I don't know how to use the price from the current Product object, instead I'm just getting `None`. I know there's probably a simple answer.

Here's my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django import forms, views
from django.db.models import Sum

class ExtendedProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    amount_spent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    #@classmethod tells the class to act on itself instead of an instance of itself
    @classmethod
    def total_amount(cls):
        #returns a dictionary
        return cls.objects.all().aggregate(total=Sum('amount_spent'))

class RevenueInfo(models.Model):
    #here we access the dictionary
    user_total = ExtendedProfile().total_amount()['total']
    total_amount_spent = models.DecimalField("Total User Revenue", max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=user_total)

class Product(models.Model):
     category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     description = models.TextField()
     #photo = models.ImageField()
     price_CAD = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
     quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=0, null=True, editable=True)
```

Here's my views

```
def product_page(request):
    all_products = Product.objects.all()
    quantity_forms = QuantityForms(request.POST)
    quantity = request.POST.get('amount')
    grand_total = RevenueInfo.user_total
    if quantity > 0:
        return HttpResponse(Product().price_CAD)
    return render(request,'tracker/product_page.html', {'all_products':all_products, 'quantity_forms':quantity_forms})
```

This is the template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% for object in all_products %}
<h3><a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ object.name }}</a></h3>
<p>{{ object.description }}</p>
<p>{{ object.price_CAD }}</p>
<form method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
{{ quantity_forms.amount }}<button>Buy</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

Right now I'm just trying to at least return the correct amount of the product the user pressed "buy" on. Then from there I'll calculate the total amount of the purchase

Comment: By doing `Product().price_CAD` you are creating new `Product` and accessing it's `price_CAD` which is obviously empty. What are you trying to achieve by this line `return HttpResponse(Product().price_CAD)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems, here the first being that you are just returning the `price_CAD` of a newly created product

```
if quantity > 0:
    return HttpResponse(Product().price_CAD)
```

This will always be None if blanks allowed or zero, if blanks not allowed.

You should be returning a product that is associated with the user. But your models do not show whether such an association even exists.

Other issues include the fact that you are not grabbing the logged in user with `request.user` and you are getting data directly off `request.POST` which is unsafe.

Comment: Yes exactly, you said it better than me. I knew I wasn't returning a product that was related to a user. But I can't figure out how to do that

Comment: First step is to add `ForeignKey`s between related models. Assuming you have done that, the next is to do a related object lookup. While I don't generally go with making drastic changes to a question after answers have been recieved. I will be happy to make additional comments if you add the relevent models.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your help, I made an edit with the models. Right now I've only made a `OneToOne` relationship for the `ExtendedProfile` class. Would I need to make a ForeignKey for let's say each `Product` attribute to each `User`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be having a purchases table? Ideal scenario for you would be to have a ManyToMany relation between products and users `through` a purchases table.

Comment: Tbh I'm still new at this, I know what a `through` table is just not sure I needed one. Never heard of a purchases table

Comment: So would each product would relate to each user "through" the 'through' table

Comment: Very likely. Obviously to give you the exact answer would need very thorough knowledge of your requirements. But yes, in most cases a through table seems to be in order in a situation like this.

Comment: I want to build an e-commerce store. Users buy products, and I want to be able to track how much they bought/spent, when they bought. That should be easy enough once everything is set up. But I just need to actually connect users with the products they bought first, and be able to manipulate that

Comment: That much I gathered. There are lots of mysql tutorials out there that discuss this very subject. Django models are basically python representations of models database tables. So reading such a tutorial would go a long way.

Comment: Gotcha, I'll go looking. Is there any tutorial you know of you'd recommend?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145251/discussion-between-amon-and-e4c5).